# Normal Subgroups of \$S_4\$

Tags: code-golf, math, permutations, abstract-algebra, classification

## Objective

Given a permutation of 4 distinct items, classify the permutation by the normal subgroup(s) it belongs.

## Input/Output Format

You gotta choose the followings as the hyperparameters for your submission:

- The 4 distinct items.
- The permutation serving as the identity permutation.

The input format is to accept a permutation of the items you chose. The items must be computably distinguishable.

The output format is flexible; you can output anything as long as the classes are computably distinguishable.

Standard loopholes apply.

In any case, an input not fitting into your format falls into *don't care* situation.

## Classification

For example, suppose you chose the numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` as the 4 items, and chose the string `0123` as the identity permutation.

- The identity permuation `0123` is classified as the member of the trivial group \$\textbf{0}\$.
- The permutations consisting of two non-overlapping swaps are classified as members of the Klein-four group \$K_4\$ minus the trivial group. Those are `1032`, `2301`, and `3210`.
- The permutations that fixes exactly one item are classified as members of the alternating group \$A_4\$ minus the Klein-four group. Those are `0231`, `0312`, `1203`, `1320`, `2013`, `2130`, `3021`, and `3102`.
- The remaining permuations are classified as members of the symmetric group \$S_4\$ minus the alternating group.

## Examples

Let's say you chose the string `READ` as the identity permutation, and chose to output the classes as numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`, respectively to the list above.

- Given the string `ADER`, output `3`.
- Given the string `ADRE`, output `1`.
- Given the string `RADE`, output `2`.
- Given the string `READ`, output `0`.

Comment: So 0132 is Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @l4m2 If you chose `0123` as the identity permutation, then no, it belongs to the last category in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ỤƑḤ_=JSƊ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a permutation of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and yields:

| classification | output |
| --- | --- |
| \$e\$ | -2 |
| rest of \$K_4\$ | 2 |
| rest of \$A_4\$ | -1 |
| rest of \$S_4\$ | 0 |

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7iXHJj7csSTe1iv4WNf//woQ8D/aWEfBREfBUEfBKBYA)** Or see [all cases](https://tio.run/##VVCxDQIxDOyZwgOkceKWBWgprYiKBv0CtDRIdFAxwJcMAKJE/B7/i4QktmURpYidO9/5DvthOJYyv8fpOj/H3XqznS7lc15Oj3q/t/l1LyCnMDMGiAFSAMo5rIC5VrVHtZcDcOrPBmoVdWRDKBiFqt/Ci0qVsa2nlbBRx4owaSXfqCIy1iTFUXLJ6P7QHJEbMGq0QeR2TCTaXsnt2BrJJMkTiH/mbEWy8NDT6VlVq/kH).

#### How?

```
ỤƑḤ_=JSƊ - Link: list of integers from [1..4], P
 Ƒ       - is (P) invariant under the application of:
Ụ        -   grade-up -> 1-indexed indices sorted by value
  Ḥ      - double -> X = 2 or 0
       Ɗ - last three links as a monad - f(P):
     J   -   range of length -> [1,2,3,4]
    =    -   (P) equals (that) (vectorises)
      S  -   sum -> Y
   _     - (X) minus (Y)
```

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

Expects a permutation of the string `"4567"` and returns `0` ... `3`.

```javascript
s=>962578>>s%530%13*2&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVI9D4JAFNv9GZdgwESj8D50gMTZwcXRhSAohnCGI/z983Tyo2vTtK/tu5dT6aqhfYzL3l5q3@Te5cVOUtZtUbiIs3W0yRbpPPOV7Z3t6lVnr7E5De3Ulp1JZp9wExtiUZMksy/cnPsD/XOZVF7cH1iUGMAqTEh5D5RJFEmQMjJkIUWwCqHziBFbWBFbSWAYJkFhjuOtHhyqFVYVxBXmhKbBE@YUeHnIA9chWG0YB7aijFuBQ4R5IFveD@Gf)

#### How?

Below is a view of the lookup bitmask and where each possible input is mapped once the expression \$(n \bmod 530)\bmod 13\$ is applied.

```javascript
00 00 11 10 10 11 00 00 00 01 00 10
11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4     2  1  0
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |     |  |  |
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |     |  |  +--> 7654
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |     |  +-----> 4657, 7564
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |     +--------> 4567
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  +--------------> 5746, 6754, 7645
 |  |  |  |  |  |  +-----------------> 4765, 6547
 |  |  |  |  |  +--------------------> 4675, 6457, 6574, 7465
 |  |  |  |  +-----------------------> 5476
 |  |  |  +--------------------------> 6745
 |  |  +-----------------------------> 4756, 5647, 5764, 7546
 |  +--------------------------------> 5674, 7456
 +-----------------------------------> 4576, 5467, 6475
```

Comment: What does `962578>>s` do though?

Comment: @DialFrost This should be read as `(962578>>((s%530%13)*2))&3` : turn `s` into a value in `0..12`, multiply it by 2, right-shift the bitmask by this amount, extract the 2 least significant bits.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 26 bytes

```python
lambda A:(2*A-A@A).trace()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY5NCsIwFIT3OcVbJiUVW11IoWDOUYtE22ig-SF9hXbtMdwURA_hTbyN0urC1cA3H8NcH37As7PjTeW7e4cq3jwbaQ6VBJHRNBKx2Aq2wCCPNWWz8Lqo4AzYzvgBtPEuIFRansiENdYBnWvaX-XrYDqUqJ1tia72kE82XUdFUjKiXICo56Dtn0mLJU94ylclywj4oC3Sniv6GSj6kn2vjOOcbw)

Uses as the four distinct items the vectors `[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]`. With this convention the input, conveniently, becomes a permutation matrix.

Outputs `2 x # fixed points A - # fixed points AA`. This maps the identity to 4, the rest of the Klein four group to -4, the rest of the alternating group to 1 and everything else to 0.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 48 bytes

```python
lambda A:sum(2*(A[a]==a)-(A[A[a]]==a)for a in A)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3DXISc5NSEhUcrYpLczWMtDQcoxNjbW0TNXWBLBAbzEnLL1JIVMjMU3DUhOoLTSvKz1XILEktKsnPzylWyMwtyC8qUShILcotLUksyczPK-YC6dKq0AHpQxbXiDbQMdQx0jGO1bTiUigoyswr0ajQSdOo0IQavmABhAYA)

Same logic but uses items `0,1,2,3` and indexing instead of matrix operations.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 14 bytes

```
5|1#.2^~#@>@C.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZCxCsIwEIZx7VMcbbEW25hLEaSlJSg4iYNrQQexSBcX3Yov4lIHV3dfxacxd-cgDiG5__58_yW3e9u_fAVRA2UOUQIacrdSBYvNavm4nJt09px2GCizvQa2sgsl4nuQwHquwMPOjuu8VRMbUtcTdWcCVeehLYMhq7F32B9P0Dg2goHsW_oI1QidmIEpSKd-QZWz6fjXpbntmmRGshPIFXSgC7rgGkkxrOmCgUaQFGP-kCjBWi4Im-1sFrYREgpLQngQnlHSmC5pPFomw8lLnBbLp_W97B8)

Found while experimenting with the cycle decomposition of each permutation.

- Category 1 (`0 1 2 3`) has four individual cycles of length 1.
- Category 2 (e.g. `1 0 3 2`) has two cycles of length 2.
- Category 3 (e.g. `0 2 3 1`) has one cycle of length 3 and another cycle of length 1.
- Category 4 (e.g. `0 1 3 2` or `1 2 3 0`) has either

  - three cycles of length 1, 1, 2, or
  - a single cycle of length 4.

By squaring and summing the cycle lengths, we get

- Category 1: 4
- Category 2: 8
- Category 3: 10
- Category 4: 6 or 16

Now we can take these values modulo 5 to get 4, 3, 0, 1 for each category.

```
5|1#.2^~#@>@C.  Takes a permutation containing 0, 1, 2, 3
            C.  Cycle decomposition
        #@>@    Length of each cycle
     2^~        Square
  1#.           Sum
5|              Modulo 5
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
§SAKS0⊘ΣＥθ⁺⁼ικ⁼ι⌕θκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCQynY0TvYQElHwSMxpyw1RSO4NFfDN7FAo1BHISCntFjDtbA0MadYI1NHIVtTRwHBc8vMSwEpytaEAuv//6OjjXUUjHQUDHUUDGJj/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of 4 integers `0..3` (+2 bytes to take input as a string of digits) and outputs a code letter `0KAS` (-5 bytes to port @Albert.Lang's answer, and probably also the same length to port @JonathanAllan's answer). Explanation: Calculates the number of elements of cycle length `1` plus the number of elements of cycle length `1` or `2` (so elements of cycle length `1` get counted twice) and looks up the result.

```
 SAKS0              Literal string `SAKS0`
§                   Indexed by
         θ          Input list
        Ｅ           Map over elements
            ι       Current element
           ⁼        Equals
             κ      Current index
          ⁺         Plus
               ι    Current element
              ⁼     Equals
                ⌕   Index of
                  κ Current index in
                 θ  Input list
       Σ            Take the sum
      ⊘             Halved
                    Implicitly print
```

| Cycles | Order | Sign | Length 1 | Length 2 | Total | Classification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1+1+1+1 | 1 | `+` | 4 | 0 | 8 | `0` |
| 2+1+1 | 2 | `-` | 2 | 2 | 6 | `S` |
| 2+2 | 2 | `+` | 0 | 4 | 4 | `K` |
| 3+1 | 3 | `+` | 1 | 0 | 2 | `A` |
| 4 | 4 | `-` | 0 | 0 | 0 | `S` |

- My original answer counted the number of elements of cycle length `1` and then distinguished between `2+2` and `4` by checking for an element of cycle length `2` rather than counting the number of such elements.
- @alephalpha's answer checks the sign of the permutation and returns `0` if it's `-` or the order if it's `+`.
- @Albert.Lang's answer subtracts the number of elements of cycle length `2` from the number of elements of cycle length `1`.
- @JonathanAllan's answer subtracts the number of elements of cycle length `1` from `2` if the order is a factor of `2` or `0` if it is not.

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 33 bytes

```
p->if(permsign(p)>0,permorder(p))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWNxULdO0y0zQKUotyizPT8zQKNO0MdEC8_KKU1CIgVxOqUDUtvwgkrmGio1AAREWZeSUaQIaSgq6dgpKOQhpILVTxggUQGgA)

Takes input as a `VecSmall` of integers 1, 2, 3, 4.

If the input is an odd permutation, returns `0`. Otherwise returns its order.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
{5!#,/(x@)\'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwtjjEOwzAMA3e/QkWGxECBSjK61Esf0tlvCBD07xXJbiZFH7le1/O23R/H+e6f/fy2tswtLG20tR9RYlhOaPgTqs7ecXXaZSIUiOFjCTwQ9EkdcJKeT4JSKODzjwoVuYJiMsaQmClCiCE4B3CTWkhVCycNjdLy8voPAzMqbw==)

Port of [my own J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256066/78410).

The K code above executes the process a bit differently:

```
{5!#,/(x@)\'x}   Takes a permutation containing 0, 1, 2, 3
      (  )\'x    For each number in x, repeat and collect all values:
       x@          Index into x
   #,/           Length of flattened list
 5!              Modulo 5
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, <s>70</s> 61 bytes

```
[ "READ"<permutations> index "0332233123322323133223313"nth ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7LCoJAFN37FQc/QNLZVQiCEm1aGK3CxaS3HMpxnLliEX27TY/NeXLgnGXNvZ0P@@1us0QnuY3qvjspLX2sagdHw0i6JvcrjbSOrE/Z4UpW0w3GEvPDWKUZw4RVEAzTE1lelB7KAqWXKIssx2s@IvyocG3IdiNLVr12KZRu6I5wIUSSCBEnX05E/Pci1Nyi8utGXRSnqOBPmt6RP2UQzW8)

-9 bytes by using the string from corvus_192's [Scala 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256045/97916).

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 2](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```
s=>"033223312332232313322331"("abcd".permutations indexOf s)
```

Takes a permutation of "abcd" and returns an ascii digit by indexing into the given string.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9FoweayxByFNKvgkqLMvHRbO-eMxCLbpaUlaboWN22Lbe2UDIyNjYyMjQ2NwLSRsSGUb6ykoZSYlJyipFeQWpRbWpJYkpmfV6yQmZeSWuGfplCsCTFkszUXVwHQ6BKNNA0loPJEJU2ozIIFEBoA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>89 8</s> 87 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
f s="033223312332232313322331"!!head(elemIndices s$permutations"abcd")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNyMycwvyi0oUXBJLEvV8MotLuNIUim2VDIyNjYyMjQ2NwLSRsSGUb6ykqJiRmpiikZqTmuuZl5KZnFqsUKxSkFqUW1qSWJKZn1eslJiUnKKkCTF_e25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqCElA2UQkiC3MFAA)

A port of my [scala answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256045).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
<èāQ·Iā-0¢-
```

-7 bytes by porting [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256126/52210), since I've been unable to find anything short myself.

`[1,2,3,4]` is the identity permutation. Outputs:

- `-2` for this identity permutation itself;
- `2` for the three members of \$K_4\$;
- `-1` for the eight members of \$A_4\$;
- `0` for the remaining twelve members of \$S_4\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5vCKI42Bh7Z7HmnUNTi0SPf//2gjHUMdEx3jWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##LU67DcJADF0lSu1I2HclUhoWoLauAImCigIp0pVpGIARqNiAPmQSFjnsF3fPz@93u5/O10ub6lTHvvs9nl0/1kPbf9/rfFw@dZ2H3fIaGjVVZRJKlEshVSGmTMmgMYbFkN2mYPzZlWBdJ1C62y4g1zLcnpqBnGXkuHtL9J4UiRKN@MKDDVBCF9kpcpAXGznWYGH0IT36toVYGhyWlVL@).

**Explanation:**

```python
<      # Decrease each value in the (implicit) input-permutation by 1
 è     # 0-based index each into the (implicit) input-permutation
  ā    # Push a list in the range [1,length]: [1,2,3,4]
   Q   # Check if the two lists are equal
    ·  # Double this check (2 or 0)
I      # Push the input-permutation again: [z,y,x,w]
 ā     # Push list [1,2,3,4] again
  -    # Decrease the values at the same positions of the two lists: [z-1,y-2,x-3,w-4]
   0¢  # Count how many 0s are in the list (how many item were already at the correct
       # position)
-      # Subtract this amount from the earlier doubled check
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

---

**Original straight-forward approach (18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)):**

```python
{œIk•Lû¾hΔ>¬o∊Ì•sè
```

`"abcd"` is the identity permutation. Outputs:

- `1` for this identity permutation itself;
- `3` for the three members of \$K_4\$;
- `2` for the eight members of \$A_4\$;
- `0` for the remaining twelve members of \$S_4\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@uhkz@xHDYt8Du8@tC/j3BS7Q2vyH3V0He4BihUfXvH/f1JiSjIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY29CQJBFIRbOV58NXgN2MGxwfsRFIMLDg4WEyMRMVIrMDKwA8HgFlOL2EbWt2P0mJk38w0jy2ZVpjjFjpp8uDTUxbL7XOM27@/L9Jrf6@9tMT@HfDyls3tjepS29D2xqFFoexI2pZbUWPyYCsNmtarZpKaibPWYcv1lqUrFqjJWNIX13xQMumsYQOohBhQVL4LJYDgSc76AORCdC@UsCuEH).

**Explanation:**

```python
{             # Sort the characters of the (implicit) input-permutation string
 œ            # Pop and get all its permutations
  Ik          # Pop and get the index of the input-permutation
•Lû¾hΔ>¬o∊Ì•  # Push compressed integer 100220032002200230022003
 s            # Swap so the earlier index is at the top
  è           # Index it into the the earlier integer to get a digit
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•Lû¾hΔ>¬o∊Ì•` is `100220032002200230022003`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(`try{${s.slice(1)}}catch{3}`);bcd=0;adc=dab=cba=1;cdb=dbc=cad=dca=abd=bda=acb=bac=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLLasJgEIX3PoeQZKFoXYbxWZw5Ey8lmOIfBAl59vTQVVvOwlXgY/6Zc8mnP73gcfsaN/chu@VsS7Fj9/S@Po2P17Seyrb0N3T1vpln@IjrdJhPTRtI27WesPQwhNu@RYZlwOBpCTePtEh@ERYO@1gw3MvQd9t@uNTnunJuqZpm9RtXm@ov4Fzwzv85YvC0wEk172x16hXPnRYEDrpSmEaVNHpXmHEoxUxIYYb2lpGQ8XBpSn/yGG9Jf5CK6UM24jJSFiLTyNBpyAJYi5zGz0@wfAM)

Input a string with letter "a", "b", "c", "d". Output 0~3.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 84 bytes

```python
lambda s:locals().get(s[1:],3)
bcd=0
adc=dab=cba=1
cdb=dbc=cad=dca=abd=bda=acb=bac=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDoIwFATQfU/hjjYxRmBHMidRF/Png5pUILYbT185wHv7r762dWwL7i3zY85TmfIm5hLT5TnXWG799DiPKZgc10AXnAYZ0Qe5wU0QHS6C5jgOUAajMLT9@15rXGLHw3cptT8)

Essentially a port of [tsh's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256036).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```julia
!s=962578>>2(s%530%13)&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HY1tLMyNTcws7OSKNY1dTYQNXQWFPN@H9BUWZeSU6ehqKGiamZuaYmF0LA1MTcDEXAxNwUTcAUpOI/AA)

Port of [Arnuald's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256047/109916).

-2 thx to @Steffan

Comment: `f(s)` => `!s` using unary operators

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda s:962578>>2*(s%530%13)&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYytLMyNTcws7OSEujWNXU2EDV0FhTzfh/QVFmXolGmoaJqZm5piYXjGtqYm6GxDUxN0XhmoJk/wMA)

Port of [Arnuald's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256047/109916).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 159 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:{'1032':1,'2301':1,'3210':1,'0231':2,'0312':2,'1203':2,'1320':2,'2013':2,'2130':2,'3021':2,'3102':2,'0123':0}.get(''.join(map(str,map(x.find,y))),3)
```

I couldn't really interpret the logic. So I went with an overkill approach.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYu9DoIwFEZ3n4LttklD7s9G4kAiL9DZBYMoRn6CHSDGZ6@lHXRguifn3G9a3X0cxLfHs3/W/aWps8WsxRsIhaEgAyxIEYQJIyBLMBxAiCMQoyQQxgiMlAyTJCPIaSWEaYXE4Qc/@e3qFED@GLtB9fWkXm42213ythsas2qtjWg/zd3gVKugPFUWTAa2Kk@g9eEv2Go32DDZD5v4Bf8F)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
def f(s):
 bcd=0;adc=dab=cba=1;cdb=dbc=cad=dca=abd=bda=acb=bac=2
 try:return eval(s[1:])
 except:return 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLCsIwEEX3/Yrs2i4Ea3eV@RJxMY8UBamlRtGvjxdFJANdtdxJMufc@ZVO16nP2eIYxubWDlUQNdru2ZSMhVSYur2akImSspEpE4uRGL4qJKy0q0JaXsMS032ZQnzwpbkduuHYViE@Nc7pN@rzvJyn1IxNzVhUt231DepN/fvFTLD@P0OgYCkCA9jabQZucZjBXgQCkTKAVbkQimUA35IA8mWAJlaRxAnhsjlG9xxec4zqCEDkWmInjpKchYm3cNWgKndCP9XnNw)

Port of [tsh's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256036/114446). Input as a string with letters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Output as a number, 0 to 3.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, I basically just copied his footer and replaced `console.log` with `print`. I didn't really check whether it was right.